# Handling ID numbers in K means Clustering

Tags: data-science, k-means

I am new to machine learning. I want to know how to deal with categorical data when there are large amount of them. For example i have a Feature of customer ID (example - 255458565) and there a nearly 100000 customers. How can i add this feature into K means without getting affected by its big id number.

Answer (score 0):

You can split all of your customers to some groups. And add binary coded groups to your model. For example good customers and bad customers. You can make more groups!